# Result Data structure of Doctrine Join

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Using this Query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
$qb->leftJoin('r.users', 'u')
    ->addSelect('count(u.id) as user_count')
    ->groupBy('r.id');
```

I get result-set:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 45
                    [role_name] => ROLE_ADMIN
                    [description] => Admin roles
                )

            [user_count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 47
                    [role_name] => ROLE_OPERATOR
                    [description] => Operator role
                )

            [user_count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 48
                    [role_name] => ROLE_TEST
                    [description] => ROLE_TEST
                )

            [user_count] => 0
        )

)
```

Is there a smart way of transforming all the properties the same level? As  now a roles are in sub Array with 0 key.

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 45
            [role_name] => ROLE_ADMIN
            [description] => Admin roles
            [user_count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 47
            [role_name] => ROLE_OPERATOR
            [description] => Operator role
            [user_count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 48
            [role_name] => ROLE_TEST
            [description] => ROLE_TEST
            [user_count] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: I think there is no chance to this, because the first select is the object itselfs and the second is an additionally select stmt. If `user_count` would be an attribute of your object this would work.

Comment: But I think you can count the `users` on your `$role` object if you have an `->getUsers()` method in your `Role` class?

Comment: @Fabian, yes, there is `Role::getUser()` method in a entity. How do I add count to a result-set in this case?

Comment: For exmaple implement a method called `getCountUsers()` there you could `return count(self::getUser());`

Comment: Well, yes, this is clear, but does it mean I need to call `getCountUsers()` looping through a result-set?

Comment: Yes. Or you can create an new attribute on your Role entity called `private $countUsers` and use https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html to set this value on `postLoad `

Comment: Nice! I like the later solution! Thanks! Please add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

> I think there is no chance to this, because the first select is the
>   object itselfs and the second is an additionally select stmt. If
>   user_count would be an attribute of your object this would work.

Instead you could add an new attribute called `private $countUsers` on your Role entity and set its value with Doctrine LifecycleCallbacks event `PostLoad`

Symfony implentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html

Doctrine events: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Comment: Is it possible this $countUsers not to be added to Schema?

Comment: Yes don't put any relevant doctrine annotions above it

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks!